# Calculator with multiple inputs to add up

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

Can someone look over my code and clean it up?

I am trying to make a calculator with multiple inputs to add up. This is a snippet of the code that just needs to be cleaned up and shortened and I am relatively new to python so if anyone wants to clean this up thank you.

```
#functions
def x():
    #needed for the the loop later
    x.x = int(input("Type how many numbers you would like to add up: "))
    x.xCON = int(input("Please confirm by typing the same number: "))

#welcome to the code
print("Would you like to add up lots of numbers?")
print("If so you came to the right place")

#neaten up
print("________________________________________________")

#run function
x()

#cheack if the numbers are the same if not they have to retype them
if x.x == x.xCON:
    #neaten up
    print("____________________________________")
    #setting veriables for the loops and the list of the numbers
    i = 0
    nums = []
    #while i is not = to the input number(x.x) do the loop
    while i != x.x:
        #asks for the numbers to be added up
        INTnum = float(input("Write the numbers to be added up: "))
        #adds the numbers to the list
        nums.append(INTnum)
        #updates the veriable cheacking how many times the code has been ran
        i+=1
    #creating new veriables for the next loop
    index = 0
    ans = 0
    #while indxex is not = to the amount to numbers in the list run the code
    while index != len(nums):
        #veriable nums is now set as the lists index of the veriable index
        num = nums[index]
        #the ans veriable is eqal to itself + the number that was recorded from the idex
        ans = ans + num
        #moves the number along one everytime the code is run
        index+=1
    #gives the rueult of the sum
    print("\nThe sum of the numbers is", ans)
    #neaten up
    print("____________________________________________________")

#what happens if the numbers are not the same sending the bacn to the x() function       
else:
    print("The numbers were not the same.")
    x()

#end of the code
print("\nThank you for using the calculator")
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review site, the current title applies to every question on this site, and makes no attempt to explain what the code does. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for some advice on how to title the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `x` function has a few notable things:

- `x` is a very poor name. It doesn't give any hints as to what the function is supposed to do. The name of your function should let the reader of your code know what its purpose is. Something like `get_user_input` would be much better.
- You're associating data with the function object itself; essentially creating static variables. This is not a good idea though. This means that this function can only be called once before you overwrite the previous entered data. In your case here, that may not be a big deal, but it is *not* a good habit to get into. This will significantly complicate code later when you have functions that you're calling in multiple places in your code. Return the results instead.
- You're having the user enter a confirmation, but then you're checking that they match outside of the function. Just check inside the function and loop until they match.

After fixing up those points, I have:

```
def get_user_input():
    while True:
        n_numbers = int(input("Type how many numbers you would like to add up: "))
        confirmation = int(input("Please confirm by typing the same number: "))

        if n_numbers == confirmation:
            return n_numbers
        else:
            print("The numbers were not the same.")
```

They you can get rid of the `else` case at the bottom of your code. You'd then use this function like:

```
n_numbers = get_user_input()
```

And use `n_numbers` instead of `x.x`.

---

You don't do any error handling anywhere. I find it odd that in your code, you require confirmation to ensure the user didn't typo the number they entered, but you aren't protecting against them typing in nonsensical input (like `hello`). If the user types a non-number, you'll get a `ValueError` that will crash your program. You may want to consider wrapping calls to `int` and `float` in a `try`/`except` to ensure that your program won't crash.

---

This loop:

```
nums = []
while i != n_numbers:
    INTnum = float(input("Write the numbers to be added up: "))
    nums.append(INTnum)
    i+=1
```

Can be cleaned up by using a `range`:

```
nums = []
for _ in range(n_numbers):
    INTnum = float(input("Write the numbers to be added up: "))
    nums.append(INTnum)
```

Now you don't need to manually handle `i`. This can be further cleaned up by using a list comprehension:

```
nums = [float(input("Write the numbers to be added up: "))
        for _ in range(n_numbers)]
```

Whenever you find yourself manually handling loop indices like you were with `i`, there's likely a better way that handles the looping for you.

The same can be said for this loop:

```
while index != len(nums):
    num = nums[index]
    ans = ans + num
    index+=1
```

Note how you never need `index` except to access `nums`. Just loop over `nums` directly:

```
for num in nums:
    ans += num  # The same as "ans = ans + num"
```

If you need to loop over a list, just loop over the list directly.

Really though, that's just `sum`:

```
ans = sum(nums)
```

---

Your comments aren't a good use of commenting. A lot of them are simply restating what the code itself says:

```
#the ans veriable is eqal to itself + the number that was recorded from the idex
ans = ans + num

. . .

#creating new veriables for the next loop
index = 0
```

If something is already self-explanatory, don't simply restate that in a comment. Your code reads like you're under the impression that every line of code requires a comment, but this isn't true. *Ideally*, your code itself should be all the explanation the reader needs, but if more explanation is required, note why the code is unreadable or why it's behaving as it is. When half your code is comments that just restate the code, it detracts from the important part: the code.